# XGBoost Library (libxgboost.so) could not be loaded

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, xgboost

#### Problem

In a serverless project, I want to import XGBoost into a lambda written on Python. But when I'm trying to invoke the lambda, I see this error on CloudWatch:

> [ERROR] XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (libxgboost.so) could not be loaded.
>   Likely causes:
>     * OpenMP runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, libgomp.so for UNIX-like OSes)
>     * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS
>   Error message(s): ['libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory']

#### What I tried?

1. I'm running `sls deploy` on macOS so I've added `dockerizePip: true` to my serverless.yml
2. I tried to fix missing dependency by using custom Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6

   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libaio1
   ```

   [I also must specify](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#native-code-dependencies-during-runtime) library path in `dockerExtraFiles` but I have no idea where libgomp.so should be located on Linux. So, I stuck on this point.

#### My code

serverless.yml:

```
app: improve
org: kvadrug
service: testservice

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  versionFunctions: false
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  timeout: 30

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerFile: Dockerfile
    zip: true
    dockerizePip: true

functions:
  hello:
    handler: hello.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: post
          private: true
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "testservice",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Test service",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "serverless-python-requirements": "^5.1.0"
    }
}
```

requirements.txt:

```
xgboost==1.0.2
```

Comment: did you try to install `libgomp1`? https://packages.debian.org/buster/libgomp1

Comment: @jakub, no. But I have installed `libomp`. Anyway, I'm not sure if it's related, because XGBoost works locally on my mac. The problem is around AWS lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Working configuration - Python 3.7**

Tested on Mojave 10.14.6 (18G4032) and Docker v2.1.0.2 (37877).

Steps:

```
sls requirements clean
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/serverless-python-requirements/
sls deploy
```

requirements.txt:

```
xgboost==1.0.2
```

serverless.yml:

```
service: xgboost
provider:
  name: aws
  timeout:60
  runtime: python3.7

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    zip: true
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    dockerExtraFiles:
      - /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: post
          private: true
```

handler.py :

```
    try:
        import unzip_requirements
    except ImportError:
        pass

    import sys
    import glob
    import os

    def hello(event, context):
        pkgdir = '/tmp/sls-py-req/'

        print("-------- Sys Path --------")
        for p in sys.path:
            print(p)

        if os.path.exists(pkgdir):
            print("-------- Pkg Dir ----------")
            os.chdir(pkgdir)
            for file in glob.glob("*"):
                print(file)

        print("-------- Var Task ----------")
        os.chdir("/var/task")
        for file in glob.glob("*"):
            print(file)

        try:
            import xgboost as xgb
            print(xgb)
        except Exception as ex:
            template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(message)

        return True
```

**Python 3.8**

For some reason, Lambda running Python 3.8 ignores the entry for *'/tmp/sls-py-req'* on *'sys.path'*. Therefore you need to manually add the library file *'libgomp.so.1'* to the root of your application.

To give it a try, update *'runtime: python3.7'* to *'runtime: python3.8'* on serverless.yml and follow these steps:

```
sls requirements clean
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/serverless-python-requirements/
sls package
cp .serverless/requirements/libgomp.so.1 ./
sls deploy
```

**FYI - How to find the libraries location within the Lambda docker image**

Run:

```
docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint /bin/sh -u 0 lambci/lambda\:build-python3.8
```

Then:

```
find / -name libgomp.so.1
```

Comment: Thanks! The Python3.8 solution worked. The only problem is that I wasn't able to get `libgomp.so.1` until I deleted old resources folder manually. Also, the information about finding library is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, [the libraries you need are installed into](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libgomp1/filelist)

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
```

by

```
apt-get install libgomp1
```

On newer Ubuntu and CentOS, libgomp1 **is no longer installed** by default (I have just checked - I have it on xenial, don't have it on a fresh bionic).

This is on a AWS machine, unfortunately not very recent (I have no other readily available):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Oct  4  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 -> libgomp.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 138448 Oct  4  2019 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: I'm on macOS. And how do you think, were the library is installed on Amazon Linux 2 (kernel - 4.14.165-102.205.amzn2.x86_64)?

Comment: I have checked on a AWS machine I had accessible. From what I see of AWS Linux 2, it should be in the same location.

Comment: I tried to specify this path in `dockerExtraFiles:` and `include:` but I'm getting the same error. Also, I noticed that the library wasn't added to the serverless package.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, these solutions did not work for me (Python 3.6, `xgboost==1.4`, Ubuntu 18.04, aarch64).

However, I was able to get things working by pointing to the `libgomp` library packaged with the xgboost Python package.

For example, `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xgboost/lib/../../xgboost.libs/libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0`